# Connecting ultrasonic transducer to PC (Data Acquisition)

Tags: amplifier, sensor, ultrasound, data-acquisition

I'm working on one project and need some guidance.

I aim to connect an ultrasonic transducer placed on the pipe to the PC so that I can acquire the data and then process it using Python.

I did some research and found that to do it I need the following:

1. Ultrasonic transducer itself
2. Amplifier
3. Analog-to-Digital converter
4. PC with software
5. Connectors for an amplifier, converter, etc.

Is this everything I need?

What should I consider when selecting these pieces of equipment?
I'd like to hear your recommendations on them as well (i.e. which software is better, or which analog-to-digital converter is better, and so on).

Comment: For the first round, you could likely get a good start by just connecting the transducer to an oscilloscope, and collect data from that to your pc (if you want).  You may be surprised what you see.

Comment: Is there a possibility to connect an oscilloscope to PC ?

Comment: "Is there a possibility to connect an oscilloscope to PC?"  Many scopes have either a USB, Ethernet, or the venerable GPIB port(s).  Manufacturers often also supply free basic software to download data (or write your own).

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen thank you very much, really appreciate that.

Comment: What is the frequency range? Some high end sound cards can aquire analog data well above 20 kHz.

Comment: @Jens It is a 1Mhz transducer

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen How can I supply the power for an ultrasonic transducer when connecting it to the oscilloscope?

Comment: Well, you didn't mention that this is a pulse-echo system.  If it's just a receiver/detector then you do not need any power; just connect the crystal to the scope (use an x10 probe in case some higher voltages are generated).  If this is a pulse-echo system, then now things are a little more complicated, and I'd have to start charging you by the hour ;-)  Unfortunately, you would then be asking that we design a whole sub-system for you, and that is not what this site is all about.

Comment: @ChrisKnudsen thank you for the reply. Appreciate that. Seems like I need a pulse-echo system.

Comment: Once you determine your pulser/source characteristics, a simple pulse-echo interface (or build one), then I would still suggest that you start your acquisition journey with just an oscilloscope.  You mention Python.  We have developed several scope interfaces with python for Tektronix, Keysight, Bitscope (Aussies), and even Digilent's Analog Discovery.   The point is that, scripting up Python for this stuff is pretty straight forward.  Don't get hung up on buying (or designing) boutique electronics at the beginning.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's the basics.

You might want to add input (biased diodes) protection on the amplifier input. Transducers can output high voltage spikes if the face is hit. Also, a disconnected transducer can build up high voltage (couple hundred volts) whilst sitting around. When you connect the transducer to the amplifier, it could damage the amplifier input.

If the A/D converter doesn't have an anti-alias low-pass filter, you will need to add this to your list.

Depending on the transducer, frequency range of interest, and noise floor requirements; you may need a high impedance input on the amplifier (1 to 10 megohms). The high input impedance requirement becomes important when operating at lower frequencies (< 100 kHz).

As Chris stated in the comments section, connect the transducer to an oscilloscope to figure out what sort of amplification and equipment you'll need.